# Standard input(piping txt file) and .readline() results in a idling state?

Tags: java, eclipse, input, standards

I am trying to read a text file using standard input.
However, when I try to read the file line by line, it goes into infinite loop(?) state and I have to force quit the process.

I am piping data in with

```
< Input1.txt
```

and

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

However, when I try to

```
f.readLine();
```

it stalls.

#### Edit

input file

```
a = {}
b = {2*3,7,1*4,5*0,1*2}
c = b
d = {2*5,1*2,9}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I try this class:

```
public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for(String s = null; (s = b.readLine()) != null;){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

using this command line:

```
java Try < test.txt
```

and it's works fine.

Comment: thank you for the comment! All it was is I did not understand the concept of piping. Now i get it :)